# Kubernetes - ingress controller vs ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, yaml

New guy here. I was wondering if anyone could help me with the differentiating characteristics that I could use to identify ingress controllers vs ingresses via yamls and services. I have a preexisting cluster and I think the Ingress controller may have been installed via helm but I am not sure. Is there a way to get a look at the yaml that helm uses when installing the nginx ingress controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer1**

If you want to see the YAML a chart might generate you can use the template command

```
helm template rel1 repo1/chart1 -f values.yaml
```

**Answer2**

If you want to see the manifest that helm used in the past?

```
helm history myrelease -n namespace1
helm get manifest myrelease --revision 5 -n namespace1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the yaml manifest when you pass `--dry-run` flag to your helm install/upgrade command. Please refer to the official documentation https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/